# DB2: The user defined function or procedure was unable to map to a single Java method

Tags: java, db2, external, procedure

It seems as if the procedure is not able to find the java method inside the jar file,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class SecurityServiceClient {


    private static String executePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            // create connection
            URL url = new URL(targetURL);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  

            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            // send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.close();

            // check response code
            InputStream is = null;

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                is = connection.getInputStream();
            else
                is = connection.getErrorStream();

            // get response 
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            rd.close();

            return response.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
    }


    public static String getSecurityServiceAccessToken(String host, String userName, String password, String applicationInfo) {
        String targetURL = String.format("https://some/rest/service/call");
        String urlParameters = String.format("username=%1$s&password=%2$s&applicationInfo=\"%3$s\"", userName, password, applicationInfo);
        JSONObject response  = new JSONObject(executePost(targetURL, urlParameters));
        return response.getString("accessToken");
    }



}
```

This class has 2 methods:
-getSecurityServiceAccessToken() - internally calls method
-executePost()

I am trying to call the above code from the below procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schema.PROC_TEST2 (IN HOST VARCHAR(255), IN USERNAME VARCHAR(255))
LANGUAGE JAVA
EXTERNAL NAME 'jarID:SecurityServiceClient.getSecurityServiceAccessToken'
PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
```

Getting the following error:

Received error code:

> DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was
>   not a valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it
>   returned: SQL20204N  The user defined function or procedure
>   "schema.PROC_TEST2" was unable to map to a single Java method.  LINE
>   NUMBER=2.  SQLSTATE=46008

Comment: You define a routine with 2 parameters referencing method with 4 parameters. Db2 is unable to find a method getSecurityServiceAccessToken with 2 parameters and returns the error you see...

Comment: Thank You for the response. Tried adding the additional 2 parameters to match the signature, but still getting returns the same issue. Does the class that we call needs to have the main method attached to it ?

Comment: Must be 'public static void getSecurityServiceAccessToken(..., ..., ..., ...)' instead of 'public static String getSecurityServiceAccessToken(..., ..., ..., ...)'.

Comment: Would you not want to create this as a FUNCTION rather than a PROCEDURE?  Procedures can only return integer values unless you return a result set or an OUT parameter

Comment: I need to use the String to pass it to another place, I will try with function. Thank You guys for the quick responses.

Comment: @PaulVernon Even with the function, I am getting the same error. :  {0:0} The user defined function or procedure "DB2INST1.TESTUDF" was unable to map to a single Java method.. SQLCODE=-20204, SQLSTATE=46008, DRIVER=4.22.29

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer. Maybe ensure you can get the sample UDF to work https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sample.doc/doc/java_jdbc/s-UDFjsrv-java.html  then extend with your code?  One difference that I notice in your code is thatyou are missing `throws Exception` from your Java function

Comment: Have you registered your file under the jar id `jarID` https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/r0006425.html   You will get your the error message if you have not

Comment: Deploying Java routine class files to database servers:
 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0006348.html

Comment: @lamar8080 Did you resolve this?